# Knockout push new array item using Ajax form

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My application is MVC 5 c#, I am using the following form to update a table:

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddOha", "Medication", new AjaxOptions()
{
    UpdateTargetId = "result",
    OnSuccess = "getresult",
    HttpMethod = "POST"
}))
{
    <input id="MedName" name="MedName" value="" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 100px" placeholder="Value"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
}
```

Here is my Knockout list:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: OhaList">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input data-bind="value: Name" class="input-sm form-control" style="width: 100px" placeholder="Value" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.OhaList = ko.observableArray([]),
        $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("xxx", "xxx")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            self.OhaList(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
        }
    });
    var ohaMed = {
        Name: self.Name
    };
self.ohaMed = ko.observable();
}
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I tried to update the list using:

```
var getresult = function(data) {
    if (data[0].Name !== "") {
        // alert(data[0].Name);
        ViewModel.OhaList.push({ Name: data[0].Name });
        // ViewModel.OhaList.push({ Name: "1});
    } else {
        alert("failed");
    }}
```

Although I get the results from the controller, or even if I code the value, I get the following error:

```
Unable to get property 'push' of undefined or null reference
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Could you explain what's getresult function and how're you calling it?

Comment: If you are trying to update an element try modifying the JSON data then binding it in a table. [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15897629/knockout-mapping-and-foreach-data-bind-on-table-with-buttons-missing-reference)

Comment: getresult is called from the form - OnSuccess.  The controller returns the new values that I want to push to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your viewmodel handy, here's one way to do that:

```
window.viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(window.viewModel);
```

Then in your getresult function, you need to use that instance of ViewModel to push the values to, rather than the ViewModel *type* itself:

```
var getresult = function(data) {
    if (data[0].Name !== "") {
        // alert(data[0].Name);
        window.viewModel.OhaList.push({ Name: data[0].Name });
        // ViewModel.OhaList.push({ Name: "1});
    } else {
        alert("failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution.  Works great, I appreciate your assistance.